# Cannot pass in uniform color in fragment shader opengl

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

I am using openGL 3.1 and programming with QGLfunctions. I cannot pass in the uniform vec4 mycolor to the fragment shader I have initialized my program using:

```
m_program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram(this);
m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
m_program->link();
m_posAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("posAttr");
m_mycolor = m_program->uniformLocation("mycolor");
m_matrixUniform = m_program->uniformLocation("matrix");
```

and then I try to send color

```
 GLfloat color[] = {
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f    };
glUniform4fv(m_mycolor, 4, color);
```

to my fragment shader which is:

```
 static const char *fragmentShaderSource =
    "uniform vec4 mycolor;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = mycolor;\n"
    "}\n";
```

and I get nothing displayed

Comment: What if you use 0.5f for all four components? Sometimes it's easy to get the RGBA BGRA order mixed up and end up with a 0 alpha channel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
glUniform4fv(m_mycolor, 4, color);
```

From the `glUniform` documentation about the count parameter:

> Specifies the number of elements that are to be modified. This should
>   be 1 if the targeted uniform variable is not an array, and 1 or more
>   if it is an array.

The count parameter in your case should be 1 since your `color[]` array still only represents one `vec4` entry.

you are trying to fill a `uniform vec4 color[4]` array.

The correct version :

```
glUniform4fv(m_mycolor, 1, color);
```

As @Bahbar also pointed out : "`GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if count is greater than 1 and the indicated uniform variable is not an array variable." So.. check your GL errors!

Comment: @M_global: I'd add that: "GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if
    count is greater than 1 and the indicated
    uniform variable is not an array variable." So.. check your GL errors!